# Keep user comments on table after refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table, local-storage

I am working on creating a table where a user can come in and edit the table, I created a script where it would add to the table but when the page refreshes the comments disappear. I have read that I need some additional tools to save comments on my HTML page. Is there a way to keep the comments saved on the table?

Any feedback is appreciated.

```html
<table class="input">
  <th id="lastcomment">Comment</th>
  <th id="lastcommentdate">Tool</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
      <label for="toggle">Comment</label>
      <dialog>
        <form id="engcomment">

          <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
        </form>

        <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
        <label for="toggle">close </label>
      </dialog>
      <p><span id='display'></span></p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can save data to [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not familiar with the server-side, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on the client-side to resolve it.

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)
> object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across
> browser sessions

```
const localStorageKey = "myData";
document.getElementById("user_input").value = getDataFromLocalStorage();
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = getDataFromLocalStorage();

function showInput() {
  var user_input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  setDataToLocalStorage(user_input);
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = user_input;
}

function setDataToLocalStorage(newData){
   localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, newData);
}

function getDataFromLocalStorage(){
  return localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) || "";
}
```

[Demo on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/parsonsnguyen/pen/eYdQojB?editors=1111)

> [Becasue SO disallowed to use HTML5 local storage on code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets)

[image]

Comment: Say I wanted to display their name too and keep it, would I just create another variable of localStorageKey?

Comment: Yeah, you can store all info related to your single app into one object with one localStorageKey - when you get, you have to destruct it accordingly, or you can also store another info with different key as well.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and Javascript are only for the **client-side** which can only save data on the users' own device. If you want to store those data and let everyone able to see it, you need **server-side** technology. Such as `Node.js`